# Magento - All product categories are empty (frontend)

Tags: magento, frontend, product

All my products have vanished from my website (front end). They are all in the back end and I can open them and make changes etc. But they aren't appearing when I click on one of the tabs for a certain category.

The page comes up fine with the category details and the category feature image. But no products are showing.

I am using the JoomlArt theme called JM Wall, I have just updated to the latest version 1.9.0.1 and I've tried the following; flush magento cache, flush cache storage, flush catalog images cache, flush javascript/css cache, also tried re-indexing all the data on the index management page.

Any suggestions on how to fix?

Magento ver. 1.9.0.1

Comment: Check the design package and theme defined in backend and if its the same on frontend

Comment: Did products show up correctly before update to Magento 1.9?

Comment: Some indexes cannot be run from backen. Did you try to run all indexes from shell? `php shell/indexer.php reindexall`

Comment: Yes the products all showed correctly before I done the update, I can't even access the configuration in the system back end now. It just shows a blank white page

Comment: How do I run the indexes from shell?